# 1D array passed to function as 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, performance

I have a 1D array `float64 arr[60]` being used to store voltage values from a DAQ. The array is populated as such:

```
10 SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL, 6 CHANNELS, grouped by channel
transducer_0    transducer_1   ...  transducer_6
[0, 1 ..., 9,   10, 11 ..., 19 ...  50, 51 ..., 59]
```

I would like to store this data into a 1D array of pointers and to pass to a function whose definition is: `bool func2(int samples, double* const* arr2)`

```
[channel 0]                 [channel 1]                       [channel 5]
{val 0, val 1 ...val 9},    {val 10, val 11 ...val 19},  ...
```

The values are being updated at ~5000Hz and as such I am wondering what the most efficient means might be so that I am not copying any data.

Since the data inside arr is stored in memory the same for either the 1D or 2D array am I able to just cast the pointer?

Comment: Cant you use a vector? Easier to manipulate... Just write a struct such as `struct Data{const char* channel; double val};` and add this to the vector and when you need just pull out the channel data you want.

Comment: You could cast the pointer... but it might be easier to declare a 2D array (`float64 arr[6][10]` instead of `float64 arr[60]`) in the first place, though.

Comment: The problem is the callback function fills a 1D array and I do not have access to modify the function.

Comment: It should be fine passing the 2D array to the callback, but if you like you could cast the 2D array to `float64 *` for the callback.

Comment: Wait... is that `func2` looking for an array of pointers?  That's not equivalent to a 2D array.  You need to pass an array of `float64 *`, filled with pointers to six 10-element `float64` arrays.

Comment: It appears that your func2() is not expecting a stock 2D array, but rather an array of pointer to buffers to produce a 2D effect. Data inside the array would be stored the same way for a stock 2D array, but it isn't for the array of pointers emulation of a 2D array.

Comment: Though you can always access 1D array as a 2D array. `arr[i][j]` can be accessed like `arr[j+10*i]`.

Comment: Pick a language. C *or* C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<size_t stride, class T, size_t N, size_t count = N/stride>
std::array<T*, count> make_2d( T(&raw)[N] ) {
  std::array<T*, count> retval;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    retval[i] = raw + i*stride;
  return retval;
}
```

this will return a `array` of pointers to the lower dimensions

To call `func2`, simply do:

```
func2( 10, make_2d<10>(arr).data() );
```

this assumes that the number of samples is fixed, and that you want an array of pointers to each of the samples.

The above does it with no dynamic allocation.

Note that `arr` must be of type `double arr[60]` for the above to work.  `float64` is hopefully an alias to a `double`.  If `arr` is a function parameter, even if it has the number `60`, it isn't really a `double arr[60]`, but "really" a `double*`.

This can be gotten around with a bit of creative casting:

```
using parr_t = double(*)[60];
func2( 10, make_2d<10>(*(parr_t)(arr)).data() );
```

if the same array (at the same location in memory) is being repopulated with samples repeatedly, you can do the `make_2d` call once, and use it each time.

Comment: typo line 3 in template variable size. Should perhaps be N?

Comment: @MattStokes yep.  Fixed, and improved: `count` calculation now moved to `template` arguments.

Comment: What about if I wanted access in reverse order- same channel order but with values reversed. E.g. [channel0]{val 9, val 8, val 7 ...}?

Comment: @MattStokes then you'd ask another question on stack overflow?