# Reverse channel values from 1D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 1D array float64 arr[60] being used to store voltage values from a DAQ. The array is populated as such:

```
10 SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL, 6 CHANNELS, grouped by channel
transducer_0    transducer_1   ...  transducer_6
[0, 1 ..., 9,   10, 11 ..., 19 ...  50, 51 ..., 59]
```

I would like to store this data into a 1D array of pointers and to pass to a function whose definition is: `bool func2(int samples, double* const* arr2)`

I have asked a similar question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721425/1d-array-passed-to-function-as-2d-array/30721558?noredirect=1#comment49635497_30721558) to which the accepted solution given by @Yakk was:

```
template<size_t stride, class T, size_t N, size_t count = N/stride>
std::array<T*, count> make_2d( T(&raw)[N] ) {
  std::array<T*, count> retval;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    retval[i] = raw + i*stride;
  return retval;
}
```

I am looking for help to generate the argument `double* const* arr2` for  `func2()` which is the reverse order of the values stored in the channels. E.g.

```
[channel 0]                 [channel 1]                       [channel 5]
{val 9, val 8 ...val 0},    {val 19, val 18 ...val 10},  ...
```

The input can either be the initial 1D array, or the 1D array of pointers as constructed through the templated `make_2d()` function. I'm wondering what the most efficient means to do this is as the array is being updated at a rate of 5000Hz. I'm hoping there is a way which I won't have to copy values from the input array, though I am more interested in time efficiency then space efficiency.

Currently I am creating a second array of pointers and copying the reverse channel values in.

```
  // DOF == 6, SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL = 10
  double ch0[SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL];
  double ch1[SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL];
  double ch2[SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL];
  double ch3[SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL];
  double ch4[SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL];
  double ch5[SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL];
  double* data_rev[DOF] = {
  ch0, ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5};

  // generate reversed order array
  for (int i = DOF - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    for (int j = SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL - 1; j > 0; --j) {
      data_rev[DOF - 1 - i][SAMPLES_PER_CHANNEL - 1 - j] = static_cast<double>(data[(i*10)+j]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Would storing them in reverse order suffice?  By that I mean, replace index i with (9 - i) when storing.  Or are you asking for reversal *after* storage has happened?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using arrays over vectors? Reversing a vector is [trivial](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/)

Comment: The 1D array is populated from a DAQ Library function whose input is a pointer to an array of float64s. Else absolutely vector.

Comment: I do not understand what without copying means. Without use of extra memory (as asked by @donjuedo)?

Comment: I can't modify the storage of the 1D array unfortunately which is unfortunate so I'm trying to make the most of the situation.

Comment: This process happens at 5000Hz so I'm looking for an effective means which is all I'm after by saying without copying

Comment: Store them in reverse order; start at the last position and decrement the index.  Very efficient, no additional copies or moves required.

Comment: Right, but how would you do this to pass to the function as a `double* const* arr2` where the loop is most definitely reading in sequential order. The channels need to be stored in reverse order as the pointer required to be passed must point at the starting value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is not possible:
You cannot pass an array of pointers to func2 that makes it appear as if the samples would be in reversed order (I assume, you can't modify func2), but as long as you are not working on a very low power machine, something like this is dirt cheap (both in time and space overhead):

```
double arr[60];
std::array<double,60> tmp;

int main() {
    auto t = make_2d<10>(tmp);
    std::reverse(t.begin(), t.end());

    while (true) {
        readData(arr, 60);
        reverse_copy(begin(arr),end(arr), begin(tmp));
        func2(60, t.data());
    }
}
```